# setTimeout function not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey all I have this piece of code that basically fades in whichever div it is applied to. But for some reason I cant get it to work correctly. I am able to make the text im wanting to fade in over 2s, but I cannot for the life of me get it to fade in after 2s have passed (so overall the effect should happen once the page has loaded after 2s is what im aiming for. Here is a codepen version with a slightly different jquery but still same problem http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPJaJj

Here is the jquery:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#test").fadeIn(400);
}, 5000)// JavaScript Document
```

Then here is the id div #test:

```
/*---------------------------- Content ----------------------------*/
#test p {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        margin-top:-5px;
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

and i am applying it to this html:

```
===================================================Content===================================================!-->
    <div class="contentwrap">      
        <div class="textwrap">
        <div id="test">
                <div class="contentspace">
                </div><!--close contentspace!-->
                <div class="content">       
                        <p class="headertxt">Specializations</p>
                        <p>With various skills in branding, multi-media 
                        and advertising I am able to provide fresh and inspiring solutions 
                        for the task given to me. Using various programs such as:</p>               
                        <p><img src="images/1436419348_Photoshop.png"/><img src="images/1436419350_Illustrator.png" /><img src="images/1436419354_Dreamweaver.png" /><img src=          "images/1436419357_Premiere_Pro.png" /><img src="images/1436419359_After_Effects.png" /><img src="images/1436419356_Flash_Pro.png" /></p>
              </div><!--close content!-->
                <div class="divider">
                        <img src="images/divide.png"/>
                </div><!--close divider!-->
                <div class="content2">
                    <p class="headertxt">Why me?</p>
                    <p>The work I create is reflecting something
                    fresh and exciting in order to meet the clients 
                    needs. About pushing for new and innovative ideas 
                    and pushing for an end result of brand and product growth</p>
                </div><!--close content2!-->
                <div class="contentspace">
                </div><!--close contentspace!-->
            </div><!--close test!-->
        </div><!--close textwrap!-->
    </div><!--close contentwrap!-->
    <!--
```

Hope you guys are able to solve this mystery of mine! :) shot!

Comment: Why are you are using 2 different methods to achieve `fadeIn` effect. **1)** `jQuery fadeIn()` AND **2)** `@keyframes-animation` ?

Comment: what im trying to achieve is to be able to apply this fade in effect so when the page loads within the 4s that nothing fades in (a delay basically) other stuff fades in. Then finally the css fades in....so basically make it so stuff fades in at different times. To give it an almost smooth loading effect....so i am not sure how to get it so that the css has a delay to it. Also my css seems to only work on text within a div, not actual images or backgrounds, so thats why i tried mayabe a jquer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing double animations, one throught jquery's fadeIn which is set to run after 5s and run for 400ms. And Second animation through css animations. However since css animation runs for 2 second and does the same thing as jquery one therefore you dont see jquery one run.

Remove Either one, The Css animation or Jquery one.

Increase time for Css one from 2s to 5s if you use css one.

Otherwise just removing all Css you provided will make jquery animation work.

You can easily delay css animation using css builtin support for delay

http://jsfiddle.net/zLayrwx9/

`animation: fadeIn forwards 2s 4s;`

this says use animation named fadeIn, delay it for 4s, complete it in 2s, and after completion stay in last condition.

Comment: what im trying to achieve is to be able to apply this fade in effect so when the page loads within the 4s that nothing fades in (a delay basically) other stuff fades in. Then finally the css fades in....so basically make it so stuff fades in at different times. To give it an almost smooth loading effect....so i am not sure how to get it so that the css has a delay to it. Also my css seems to only work on text within a div, not actual images or backgrounds, so thats why i tried mayabe a jquery

Comment: when i use that line of code it doesnt do anything :/ just doesnt appear

Comment: got it working finally! :) thanks for the help :) one last thing. When fading images in and moving its position its quite jittery, anyway to make that nice and smooth?

Comment: move using `transform: translate(x,y)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to trigger the CSS fade-in with a class and a JS code to apply this class to the target element after two seconds.